# jQuery ajaxSend handler target problems

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble getting the following to work in my project.

I currently have several calls to `load()` method sprinkled throughout my codebase, for example:

```
$('#cart').load('/cart/user/12312');
```

What I want to do now is attach a listener to the `#cart` dom element that when the contents of this element is loaded like above, i can execute some code to indicate it's loading.
This is what i've got up until now:

```
$('#cart').ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if ($(event.target).is('#cart')){
        $(event.target).html('loading ...');
    }
});
```

Problem I'm facing now is that this event triggers for ALL ajax requests, even the ones that don't have `#cart` as target. The `event.target` just always seems to be `#cart` or whatever I call the `.ajaxSend()` on. Even when doing a completely different `$.ajax()` or `load()` call, even not directly loading the contents into a dom element, the event triggers with `#cart` as the `event.target`

Anyone know how to solve this? I want to execute some code, only when an ajax call is dispatched which will load it's content into `#cart`

PS: I know that `ajaxSend` is one of the global Ajax events in jquery, but it should somehow be possible to derive the context of the event from the handler no?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cWRwf/1/

Comment: have you ever solved this? I have the same issue currently. I am interested in the DOM context of the submission,specifically the form contents...